# Get Raw Drive Size

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, diskspace

I need to gather volume capacity sizes for all fixed drives on a server.  I am limited to using PowerShell 2 because that is what the sysadmins have deployed on the servers.  I can get the information on the formatted drives very easily, using the `Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume` function.

```
$ComputerName = "."
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "$computername" Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType=3" | foreach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        SystemName  = $_.SystemName
        UsageDate   = $((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        Label       = $_.Label
        VolumeName  = $_.Name
        FileSystem  = if ($_.FileSystem -eq $null) {"RAW"} else {$_.FileSystem}
        Size        = if ($_.FileSystem -eq $null) {
                          Show-Capacity
                      } else {
                          $([Math]::Round(($_.Capacity/1GB), 2))
                      }
        Free        = if ($_.FileSystem -eq $null) {
                          "0.00"
                      } else {
                          $([Math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace/1GB), 2))
                      }
        PercentFree = if ($_.Capacity -gt 0) {
                          $([Math]::Round((([float]$_.FreeSpace/[float]$_.Capacity) * 100), 2))
                      } else {
                          '0.00'
                      }
    }
}
```

The `Show-Capacity` function is as follows:

```
function Show-Capacity {
    $drive=$_.Name
    $dpscript = @"
Select Volume '$drive'
Detail Volume
"@

    $Temp= @()
    [array]$Temp += ,$dpscript | diskpart
    foreach ($line in $Temp) {
        if ($line.StartsWith("Volume Capacity") ) {
            $Values = $line.Split(":")
        }
    }
    $Capacity = $Values.Trim("G", "T", "M", "B", " ")
    $Capacity[1]
}
```

The formatted drives show up correctly as follows:

```
UsageDate   : 2017-11-09 08:08:17
SystemName  : MyServerName
Label       :
VolumeName  : C:\
Size        : 99.9
Free        : 77.04
PercentFree : 77.11
```

The Raw Drives show up as follows:

```
UsageDate   : 2017-11-09 08:08:15
SystemName  : MyServerName
Label       :
VolumeName  : I:\
Size        :
Free        : 0.00
PercentFree : 0.00
```

I want Raw Drives to show up this way:

```
UsageDate   : 2017-11-09 08:08:15
SystemName  : MyServerName
Label       :
VolumeName  : I:\
Size        : 12000.0
Free        : 0.00
PercentFree : 0.00
```

In the PowerShell logs I see the error: "Cannot index into a null array. At {path}:12 char 11.  I'm also getting a trim error, but that is of lesser concern.  I've been working on this and reading lots of posts for about 2 weeks now and have not been successful.

I tried the method outlined in this line of posts:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/30/automating-diskpart-with-windows-powershell-part-5/

This will always be run on local computer, but will be exported to CSV and aggregated.

Comment: Why all the string formatting? Just select the properties you want and pipe to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: I was having issues getting Export-CSV to work correctly.  I have another script calling this one and doing the export-csv there when it loads it into SQL.  Do you think the Export-CSV would help with the diskpart information for the RAW drives?

Comment: What kind of "issues"?

Comment: mostly formatting issues.  The Date/Time information wasn't coming across with seconds and in the order I wanted it.  I never was able to get Export-CSV to do anything with the diskpart for the RAW drives though.

Comment: RAW partitions don't have a filesystem, so there is no "free space" to be determined via the `Win32_Volume` class. You need to get the size information via the `Win32_DiskPartition` class.

Comment: I knew I can't get free space, but was looking to get capacity.  I was not aware of the Win32_DiskPartiton class.  That is exactly what I need.  Is there an easy way to match the Disk #2, Partition #0, etc. to an assigned drive letter?

Comment: http://community.idera.com/powershell/powershell_com_featured_blogs/b/tobias/posts/finding-related-wmi-classes-and-drive-letters

The link has a PowerShell Script for doing that exact join.
Thank you